# How can I put '!=' with an array in where in Laravel Query builder?

Tags: laravel

How can I write not equal in where in laravel query builder ?

I would like to query like this
e.g.

select * from Table where a != '1' and  a != '2'  and  a != '4' and  a != '6' ;

```
$removeIdListArray = (1,2,4,6);

$removedIdList =  Stack::
            ->where('columnA',$removeIdListArray);

//↑What should I do?
```

Comment: You have a syntax error: `$removeIdListArray = (1,2,4,6);` should be either `$removeIdListArray = array(1,2,4,6);` or `$removeIdListArray = [1,2,4,6];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `whereNotIn` and pass an array as the second parameter

```
$removeIdListArray = [1,2,4,6];

$removedIdList =  Stack::whereNotIn('columnA', $removeIdListArray);
```

Reference: [Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

The most fluent way :

```php
Model::query()->whereNotIn('column', $arrayOfValues);
```

I will recommend you always using query() method together with your models, since it will allow you to explore all of the available options for the Laravel Model class

Answer (score -1):

Simply :

```
->where('columnA', '!=', $removeIdListArray);
```

or

```
->whereNot('columnA', $removeIdListArray);
```

Comment: `where()` and `whereNot()` are for single values, not multiple.

Comment: Yeah you right i did not look at the value of the OP, i assumed it was a single value, since he was using where() already